# Multiple recipients in mailto tag invoked from WPF/WinForm browser control

Tags: asp.net, html

Does anyone know how to construct a mailto tag with multiple recipients that will be work in a WPF/WinForms browser control.

The format I am using is

```
mailto:email1@test.com;email2@test.com
```

For some reason I am not able to launch regular outlook when clicking this link in the browser control. It does however work for a single email address.

Furthermore I am able to get it to work with multiple reciepient in standard Internet Explorer using the same link format (The normal browser instead of the browser control)

The link is built dynamically, so it has to work for a variable list of recipients

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that multiple recipients after **mailto:** aren't officially supported - [see this link](http://www.sightspecific.com/~mosh/WWW_FAQ/multrec.html).
However, you can use the **cc** and **bcc** tags, e.g.

```
<a href="mailto:noone@snai1mai1.com?subject=test&cc=buddys@snai1mai1.com,
         buddy2@snail1mail.com&bcc=secretfriend@snai1mai1.com" >Send email</a>
```

Which works fine in the WPF browser. (Note: remove the line break which is only there for formatting.)

Comment: The problem I am facing is that I have a variable list of emails,so I can't use the cc/bcc solution. The link is built dynamically

Comment: @tgh: Is it not possible to dynamically build a cc list?

Comment: I ended up going with this solution. Will award the points when the site allows it...

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Phil's answer above, you can statically set `mailto:myself@mydomain.com`, or `mailto:blackhole@mydomain.com`, then dynamically create the cc/bcc fields with the list of addresses to whom you want to send the email.  That way, you still follow conventions of only one email in the mailto field, but you also can continue to dynamically create the list of recipients in the cc/bcc field.

Especially if this is being sent to people who don't know each other (as in a mailing list), the best practice is to put those emails in the BCC field so people's email addresses are kept private (BCC == Blind Carbon Copy).

**EDIT:** An alternative might be to use JavaScript on the link and use `location.href=mailto:person1@domain.com,person2@domain.com`, but I can't guarantee it will work =/

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but the recipients are supposed to be the direct recipients, so it probably doesn's make sense to just cc them on the email. . I might be out of luck on this one :-)

Comment: I'm curious as to why it matters whether the recipient's email appears in the CC or the TO field, especially if it is a mass email.

Comment: It's not really a mass email. It's the same email going to the same person with potential for more than one email address pointing to the same person

Comment: If they have a primary email they list, can you not set that as the TO field, then CC all the other possible email addresses?  Otherwise, why not then set 1 of them arbitrarily as the TO and the others as CC?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
mailto:email1@test.com?to=email2@test.com&to=other@email.com&to=more@emails.com
```

So you can add multiple `to=...` in order to add many recipients in the to field..

You can of course replace the `to` with `cc` or `bcc` to add multiple recipients to those fields..

***disclaimer**: it might not be the official way to do this, but it seems to be supported by most clients i used..*